# Trouble with findAssocs from package tm

Tags: r, text-mining

I am attempting to find words associated with a particular word in a term document matrix using the tm package.

I am using `findAssocs` to do this. Arguments for `findAssocs` are:

- x: A term-document matrix.
- term: A character holding a term.
- corlimit: A numeric for the lower correlation bound limit.

I am consistently getting `numeric(0)` as my result

Example:

```
findAssocs(test.dtm, "investment", 0.90)
>numeric(0)
```

Does anyone have familiarity with `findAssocs` and know what I am doing wrong? Or does anyone know more broadly what the `numeric(0)` result could mean?

Thank you very much in advance for any help.

Comment: I'm sure if you'd provide a reproducible example you'd figure it out yourself.

Comment: I'm not sure why this question is receiving a bounty, there is already a perfectly good answer : the threshold is too high, so no word is associated

Answer (score 2):

This result indicates that there are no words associated in 0.90 of documents with the term "investment". Try a lower threshold like 0.05 and work your way up to a threshold that yields fewer terms.

Answer (score 2):

I'm getting the same `numeric(0)`, I think it's because there is only one document in my `Corpus`, so the `document term matrix` only have one column. You may want to test `TermDocumentMatrix()` and see if you have a `multi-column matrix`. 
That said, how do I find association within one document?.

Comment: This isn't actually an answer.

Comment: @Dason, I agree, but it's a helpful clue. Faced with the same error message, I tested the claim, that `findAssocs` doesn't work when there's only one doc in the tdm, but works fine when there's more than one doc.

Answer (score 0):

It does appear this functionality only works when analyzing multiple text documents.  The only viable solution I have come up with is creating a duplicate of text document and then running the analysis.  However, it is uncertain if this changes the results in any way.  Any additional feedback would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I think it also has to do with your data file. A text file should work but if it is a .csv with only one column, you will get the (0)