# findAssocs in a single document

Tags: r, text-mining

I only have one document (a survey compilation). I want to do word association within a single document with findAssocs. So far all the examples i have seen are all combination of a few documents.

```
inspect(myDtm)
A term-document matrix (864 terms, 1 documents)

Non-/sparse entries: 864/0 (what is this for?)
Sparsity           : 0% (what is this for? what does it mean if its 0%)
Maximal term length: 20 
Weighting          : term frequency (tf)
```

my data looks like this

```
unwanted               1
upgrade                3
valid                  1
```

this is my code and i end up with the results = numeric (0)

```
findAssocs(myDtm, "salary", 0.5)
numeric(0)
```

please help.

Answer (score 1):

Sparsity measures the percentage of elements (cf. cells) in the matrix that are equal to zero. When sparsity is high, you have a lot of terms that only occur in one or a few documents. You only have one document in your example, so all terms must occur in that doc. Very generally speaking a lower degree of sparsity is more useful for investigating document similarity (if that's what you're doing... it's not clear from your question).

The short answer is that your question has [already been asked and answered](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12629993/1036500): you need to have more than one doc in your dtm to calculate term associations using `findAssocs`.

You'll have to include a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) if you want any more specific help with `findAssocs`. Try using the 'crude' dataset that comes with the `tm` package and experiment with `findAssocs` to see what happens when you alter the parameters. Check out the `tm` [documentation](http://cran.r-
project.org/web/packages/tm/vignettes/tm.pdf) to see more about how to use the built-in data.

Here's an example using the built-in data, try it for yourself:

```
require(tm)
data(crude)
dtm <- DocumentTermMatrix(crude)

# one doc in dtm, doesn't work...
dtm1 <- dtm[1,]
findAssocs(dtm1, "oil", 0.01)

# ten docs, does work
dtm10 <- dtm[1:10,]
findAssocs(dtm10, "oil", 0.01)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use findAssocs by adding your data in the following manner

```
data <- data.frame(text=txt, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

tdm <- TermDocumentMatrix(Corpus(DataframeSource(data)))
```

Basically
Import your data into a "Source", your "Source" into a "Corpus", and then make a TDM out of your "Corpus"

Answer (score 0):

I couple of years late. But I ran in to the same problem recently. It is because your term-document matrix (TDM) consists of only one document. Rather, your tdm should consist of multiple documents. If you use `paste()` to retrieve text from a data frame, you should not use `paste(data$text, collapse = " ")`, but `paste(data$text)`, before turning it into a TDM.

But if you present reproducable example maybe we can help.